# 'gawk' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file. but other files in the similar path can be run in Cmd

Tags: bash, awk, cmd, path

I wan to run a code which should be read in Cmd using [gawk](http://gnuwin32.sourceforge.net/packages/gawk.htm). I have installed it in my program file directory. I also have installed another file named Grep.exe in the same directory:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/s4z58.png)
when I try to run codes with these files I can run grep in cmd but I cant run gawk which is in the same directory. see the picture:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5Qyrf.jpg)

I thought the problem is with the path so I tried different things.
1

1. defining the path in cmd with this command and [this link](https://www.windows-commandline.com/set-path-command-line/)

setx path "%path%;c:\directoryPath"

2. define path in windows env using [this link](https://docs.alfresco.com/4.2/tasks/fot-addpath.html)
3. Installing in different directory and adding env path
4. renaming the gawk.exe to ggawk.exe and trying to run
5. installing in other computrs
   none of them work.
   I dont know what is the reason that it can read other files in the same directory but not this specific .exe file that I need.

Comment: Don't make us chase links to understand you: [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: You're obviously running into this problem in windows and it's not an issue with awk or grep but instead your environment ot being able to find tools so if you tag your question with windows it'll be more likely to attract the attention of someone who knows anything about this.